# MapResult with CypherDSL

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have this query, built with cypher-dsl (b/c the `MATCH`-clause is dynamic) and the result-set contains nodes which are represented by `@NodeEntity` annotated POJOs (amongst other columns).

My question is: Is there a way to have the result of a dynamic (non-annotated) query, wrapped into a `@MapResult` (or a regular Map with NodeEntities as values)?

The following approach doesn't seem to work, because the inferred type of `GraphRepository` has to be either a Node- or RelationshipEntity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Customer {
    @GraphId
    Long id;
    ...
}

@MapResult
public interface CustomerQueryResult {
    @ResultColumn("cust")
    Customer getCustomer();
    @ResultColumn("val1")
    int getVal1();
    ...
}

public interface CustomerQueryRepository extends GraphRepository<CustomerQueryResult> {
}

@Service
public class SearchService {
    private CustomerQueryRepository repo;
    ...

    @Inject
    public SearchService(CustomerQueryRepository repo, ...) {
        this.repo = repo;
        ...
    }

    public Iterable<CustomerQueryResult> search(...) {
        Execute cyQuery =
            start(...)
            ...
            .returns(
                "cust",
                "val1",
                ...
            );
        return this.repo.query(cyQuery.toString(), ...);
    }
}
```

I'm using spring-data-neo4j version `2.3.0.M1`

thanks for your help, in advance

---

**Update:**
Ok, using `Neo4jTemplate`'s `query` and `convert` methods, do the job:

```
@Inject
public SearchService(Neo4jTemplate template, ...) {
    this.template = template;
    ...
}

public List<QueryResult> search(...) {
    List<QueryResult> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Execute cyQuery =
        start(...)
        ...
        .returns(
            "cust",
            "val1",
            ...
        );
    for (Map<String, Object> res : this.template.query(cyQuery.toString(), ...)) {
        Customer cust = this.template.convert((NodeProxy)res.get("cust"), Customer.class);
        result.add(new QueryResult()
            .setCustomer(cust)
            ...
        );
    }
    return result;
}
```

(assuming that Customer is a class now and not an interface anymore)

However, is there maybe a better way to do it?

Comment: If your "Update" is actually something that answers the question, you post it as an answer. Self-Answered questions are encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `query(...).to(CustomerQueryResult.class)`.

And there is also the `CypherDslRepository` that you can use to run your queries and you get a `EndResult` which you can use `to(CustomerQueryResult.class)` on.

```
public interface CypherDslRepository<T> {
    Page<T> query(Execute query, Map<String, Object> params, Pageable page);
    Page<T> query(Execute query, Execute countQuery, Map<String, Object> params, Pageable page);
    EndResult<T> query(Execute query, Map<String, Object> params);
}


public interface CustomerQueryRepository extends GraphRepository<Customer>, 
                                                 CypherDslRepository<Customer> {
}
```

Comment: `this.template.query(cyQuery.toString(), ...).to(CustomerQueryResult.class)` works fine, thanks. The `CypherDslRepository` approach looks temptimg, however I already receive a RuntimeException "Cannot extract single value from Iterable with more than one elements", while calling `query` on the `CustomerQueryRepository`, before I'm able to call `result.to(CustomerQueryResult.class)`.

Comment: @michael-hunger did you mean to say this: `templateRepository.query(query.toString(), map).to(CustomerQueryResult.class);` also what is use and role of `Map<String,Object>` as 2nd parameter ? also I dont think `CypherDslRepository` will allow us to fetch column alias or Map Result such as `root.id AS someValue` kind of data... I tried but could not it always return you `Page<T>` or `EndResult<T>`